# Javascript: Replace only text inside <p></p>?

Tags: javascript, html, replace, paragraph

how can I replace only the text inside `<p></p>` without removing any other element inside ?

It look actually like this :

```
<div class = "text">
    <p>
        "Old text 1 "
        <img src="http://urlofimage.com"> 
        "Old 2"
    </p>
</div>
```

And I would like to get that :

```
<div class = "text">
    <p>
        "New text 1 "
        <img src="http://urlofimage.com"> 
        "New text 2"
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate `childNodes` of `p` and look for **text nodes**

```
var p = document.querySelector( ".text p" );
Array.from( p.childNodes ).forEach( s => {
   if ( s.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && s.textContent.trim().length > 0 )
   {
      //change the value here
   }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var p = document.querySelector(".text p");
Array.from(p.childNodes).forEach( (s, i) => {
  if (s.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && s.textContent.trim().length > 0) {
     s.textContent = "new value" + i;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>
    "Old text 1 "
    <img src="http://urlofimage.com"> "Old 2"
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<body>

<div class = "text">
    <p>
        <span id="text1">New text 1 </span>
        <img src="http://urlofimage.com"> 
        <span id="text2">New text 1 </span>
    </p>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Change Text</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = "Hello there";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Enclose the text with  and unique id.

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to specify something: I'm doing it via a script, so I can't modify the page itself. Your solution works fine, but as I said I can't use it. sorry!

Answer (score 0):

```
data = $('.text p').html().trim().split('\n')
```

This will give you array of size 3 in which image component will be at 2nd index so what you can simply do is add your updated values at data[0] and data[2] and then using .toString() function you can get simple string of updated contents which you can update at  $('.text p').

```
data[0] = '"New text 1 "';
data[2] = '"New text 2"';

var updatedString = data.toString();
$('.text p').html(updatedString);
```

There might be some typo because I didn't executed this script but this logic should work.

**++++++++++++++ Update +++++++++++++++++**

It's working fine on my machine, just added code to handle comma, here is the complete code :

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        data = $('.text p').html().trim().split('\n')
        data[0] = '"New text 1 "';
        data[2] = '"New text 2"';
        console.log(data);
        var updatedString = data.toString();
        updatedString = updatedString.replace(/,/g, "\n");
        $('.text p').html(updatedString);
    })
```

Comment: It does remove the image, sadly :/

Comment: how is that even possible ? are you sure you are not adding text at data[1] instead data[2] ?

Comment: No, I copypasted the 5 lines you wrote and it removed it. It gaves me that : "New text 1 ",,"New text 2"